# div being pushed down in Firefox

Tags: html, css

Please check out this website --> http://justicecup.radiantwebtools.com/

The section underneath the nav/logo/social-media area is further apart in Firefox as opposed to Chrome/Safari (the desired separation).

The issue seems to have to do with this part of the HTML:

```
<div class="header-container">...</div> <!--- Okay... --->
<div class="row content"> <!--- DevTools shows this the right underneath the header area...okay, thats correct --->
    <div class="width-container">...</div> <!--- on Chrome/Safari it's good.  On Firefox, this is pushed down further....why? --->
</div>
```

I have tried giving the header area some css to work against this, to no avail

```
.header-container { overflow:none;}
```

This screenshot shows the difference too --> http://screencast.com/t/CrF9HEaki

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue might have something to do with [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).

One fix for the issue, is to change the two rules below:

```
#template .content .story-primary {
    margin-top: 28px;
}
#template .content .story {
    margin-top: 62px;
}
```

to:

```
#template .content .story-primary {
    padding-top: 28px;
}
#template .content .story {
    padding-top: 62px;
}
```

Comment: @Mr.Loop:  I see that you used my solution on your site. Don't forget to mark/check the tick next to the answer and under the arrows to mark the answer as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Although my problem wasn't so exposed, it had to do with margins, thanks, at least you got me in the right direction. It's weird though since I had given a margin to a div that was within a wrapper and since it had about 5 divs behind it (siblings) I never thought about it being the issue, I had to go through all those divs to try and find the problem, by deleting nodes from the inspector panel until that spacing disappeared. Hope this helps someone else^^

Answer (score 0):

Your page layout is quite complex and I think part of your problem stems from using `.width-container` in two unsuitable places. I've been fiddling with the css using the browser's inspect element, however when I change the styling in one it cascades to the other. I think a redesign of your page would be helpful. I would suggest enclosing the whole page content (excluding the background) in a div and applying the width-container styling to that.

```
<div id="body">
    <div class="width-container">
        <div id="templatewrapper"> ... </div>
        <div id="templatefooter"> ... </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Next you should rename the width-container around the header stuff to something more appropriate.

```
<div id="page-header">
    <div class="logo"> ... </div>
    <div class="rwtmodule navigation-module meganav"> ... </div>
    <div class="social-media"> ... </div>
</div>
```

After doing this you should replace the `float:left;` on the logo, navigation and social media to `display:inline-block` and get rid of the various `margin`s. Then apply a `padding` or `margin` to the `#page-header` to push them down. The `.logo` and `.social media` will be in the wrong place but you can use `position:relative` and `top:/*some value*/` to correct this.

After doing this, the site should look like the current firefox version in both firefox and chrome. You can then move the main body of the page up using relative positioning as you did with the logo and social media.

Remember to test this out in a safe location first!

Hope this helps.